# Add label or modifying widget on django-filter form

Tags: django, django-tables2, django-filters

I'm looking for a way of specifying what the select fields in the filter form are for, this is how it looks like right now:

[image]

And is hard to understand what the select inputs are for, the ideal would be to change the default option ("Unkown" and "--------") but it should be custom for each one. Already tried that but couldn't find a way to do it, it is possible?
If someone knows a way of doing this it would be great.

Adding a label should be the easier way, but don't know how to do it.

filters.py

```
class PatientFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = {
            'dni': ['exact'],
            'first_name': ['icontains'],
            'last_name': ['icontains'],
            'risk': ['exact'],
            'status': ['exact'],
            'ubication': ['exact'],
            'supervisor': ['exact'],
        }
```

HTML

```
    {% if filter %}
        <form action="" method="get" class="form form-inline">
            {% bootstrap_form filter.form layout='inline' field_class="mr-3 mt-3" %}
            <div class="mt-3">
            {% bootstrap_button 'Filter' button_class="btn-secondary" %}
            <a href="{% url 'patients' %}" class="ml-3 btn btn-secondary">Clear</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
```

The select inputs are foreign keys, here is its definition in models.py

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
ubication = models.ForeignKey(Ubication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
supervisor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

I'm using tables2 with django-filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by adding `empty_label` to your `ModelChoiceFilter`s.

```
class PatientFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    ubication = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Ubication.object.all(),
        empty_label="Placeholder",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = {
            'dni': ['exact'],
            'first_name': ['icontains'],
            'last_name': ['icontains'],
            'risk': ['exact'],
            'status': ['exact'],
            'ubication': ['exact'],
            'supervisor': ['exact'],
        }
```

**Edit:**
For adding `placeholder` to `CharField`s you can try this:

```
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput  


class FooFilter(filters.FilterSet):
     bar = filters.CharFilter(..., widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'baz'}))
```

Comment: Note that you can't add `empty_label` to `CharFilter`s, you add **placeholder** to them by using `widget`

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted Ty! (`ModelChoiceFilters` goes without 's' and `object` with 's', in case you wanted to edit it). I could do something similar with the status field (Just had to change `ModelChoiceFilters` by `ChoiceFilter` and `queryset` by `choices`). But couldn't do it with risk (which is a boolean field not a foreign key or charfield). Any idea how to fix that? This is what I tried:
`risk = django_filters.BooleanFilter(empty_label="Risk")` But I get the error `unexpected keyword argument 'empty_label'`

Comment: Sorry for the typo mistake I fixed it, I'm not sure if you can add `placeholder` to Boolean fields try `label` instead. notice that `empty_label` is just for `ChoiceField`s, for `CharField` you should add `placeholder` instead. I will update the answer for adding `placeholder` to `CharField`s.